# SQL Syntax SELECT and Sub SELECT and JOIN

Tags: sql-server, syntax, left-join, where-clause, subquery

I have a `SELECT` statement **(e)** which produces a result set. I want to reduce the result set to only the latest version of the data, so i put a `WHERE` clause at the end of my select, which reads `WHERE e.[Version] = (SELECT MAX(e.[Version]) FROM [dbo].[d_bpcunits])`.
I then `JOIN`ed another table **(f)**  `LEFT JOIN [dbo].[d_bpc] as f on e.[bu_product_code] = f.idbpc` to the record set because I want consistent data showing up from a master table, rather than inconsistent info that users have entered. I then use many of the fields from **(f)** to replace the fields from **(e)** , which should result in the clean data set I want.

This is one of 4 result sets that I intend to `UNION ALL` together to enable me to use in a large analysis.

I'm running SQL Server 14.0.

My select query follows:

```
SELECT
e.[bu_product_code] AS ProductCode
,f.[bpc_desc] AS Description
,NULL AS BPCCountry
,f.[bpc_business_nature] AS BusinessNature
,e.[bu_year_month] AS YearMonth
,f.[bpc_active_ingredient] AS ActiveIngredient
,f.[bpc_ai_content] AS AIContent
,f.[bpc_formulation_type] AS FormulationType
,f.[bpc_brand] AS Brand
,f.[bpc_min_pack] AS MinPack
,f.[bpc_product_category] AS ProductCategory
,e.[bu_entity] AS Entity
,e.[bu_ship_to_ctry] AS ShipToCtry
,e.[bu_ccy] AS CCY
,e.[bu_data_type] AS DataType
,NULL AS ProductType
,e.[bu_latest] AS Latest
,e.[Version] AS Version
,e.[bu_account] AS UAccount
,e.[bu_entity_code] AS UEntityCode
,e.[bu_interco_code] AS UIntercoCode
,e.[bu_pic] AS Upic
,e.[bu_source] AS USource
,e.[bu_sales_rep] AS USalesRep
,e.[bu_qty_type] AS UQtyType
,e.[bu_amount] AS UAmount
FROM
[dbo].[d_bpcunits] e
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[d_bpc] as f on e.[bu_product_code] = f.idbpc
WHERE e.[Version] = (SELECT MAX(e.[Version]) FROM [dbo].[d_bpcunits])
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: What is the actual error you are getting?

Comment: Do you expect every product (or whatever entity is represented in d_bcpunits) to have the same set of values for Version so that retrieving version 4 retrieves all products since they all have a version 4 row? Or is it possible that product X has never changed so it is at version 1 while product Y is at version 4?

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I see in your query is the last line

```
  --SELECT MAX(e.[Version]) FROM [dbo].[d_bpcunits]
```

which needs to change to

```
    SELECT MAX([Version]) FROM [dbo].[d_bpcunits]
```

Then the query becomes

```
SELECT
e.[bu_product_code] AS ProductCode
,f.[bpc_desc] AS Description
,NULL AS BPCCountry
,f.[bpc_business_nature] AS BusinessNature
,e.[bu_year_month] AS YearMonth
,f.[bpc_active_ingredient] AS ActiveIngredient
,f.[bpc_ai_content] AS AIContent
,f.[bpc_formulation_type] AS FormulationType
,f.[bpc_brand] AS Brand
,f.[bpc_min_pack] AS MinPack
,f.[bpc_product_category] AS ProductCategory
,e.[bu_entity] AS Entity
,e.[bu_ship_to_ctry] AS ShipToCtry
,e.[bu_ccy] AS CCY
,e.[bu_data_type] AS DataType
,NULL AS ProductType
,e.[bu_latest] AS Latest
,e.[Version] AS Version
,e.[bu_account] AS UAccount
,e.[bu_entity_code] AS UEntityCode
,e.[bu_interco_code] AS UIntercoCode
,e.[bu_pic] AS Upic
,e.[bu_source] AS USource
,e.[bu_sales_rep] AS USalesRep
,e.[bu_qty_type] AS UQtyType
,e.[bu_amount] AS UAmount
FROM
[dbo].[d_bpcunits] e
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[d_bpc] as f on e.[bu_product_code] = f.idbpc
WHERE e.[Version] = (SELECT MAX([Version]) FROM [dbo].[d_bpcunits])
```

Comment: Dear DhruvJoshi, thanks for your comment. I just tried it and it works. Such a simple mistake and simple fix, yet caused so much hassle. I really appreciate your support. Best regards, BB.